# In-App Billing Plugin for Xamarin AcknowledgePurchase is not working

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-inapp-purchase

I am using the In-App Billing Plugin for Xamarin and Windows to implement non-consumable in-app purchases.
I have an issue that the payments are refunded for Android devices because I didn't implement the Acknowledge purchase.
The documentation advises adding the code below, but I still get a refund within three days of an item has been purchased.

```
if(purchase.State == PurchaseState.Purchased)   
{
    if (DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android)
    {             
       await billing.AcknowledgePurchaseAsync(purchase.PurchaseToken);
    }
       //consume an item          
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are not storing the result - change it to

```
BillingResult billingResult = await inAppBilling.BillingClient.AcknowledgePurchaseAsync(acknowledgePurchaseParams);

if (billingResult.ResponseCode == BillingResponseCode.Ok)
{
// whatever you need to do with the result
}
```

Note my code is not using the plugin. But you need to do the check to see what the billingResult.ResponseCode is to be able to debug it.

If you are doing this within a fragment then you will also need to do the same in your MainActvity's OnResume, as there maybe a delay before you get a BillingResponseCode.Ok. Read the Android docs about the reasons for the delay. https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/06/meet-google-play-billing-library.html

Also note that you should verify the PurchaseToken against your backend server before acknowledging the purchase.

Comment: My plugin actually returns this code back to you -> https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin/blob/master/src/Plugin.InAppBilling/InAppBilling.android.cs#L293

So you could log that back to make sure it is good to go. I use the same logic in my apps and haven't had any issues.

Comment: I will try to log the result per your suggestion. if the same code is working on your end, do you have any suggestion why the purchase is cancelled and refund within 3 days.

Comment: The most likely reason is that your acknowledgement wasn't successful, that is why you need to check the ResponseCode. Debug it or use App Center's Analytics.TrackEvent("Purchase not acknowledged  - BillingResult.ResponseCode should be OK", eventProperties);